# terminating with uncaught Exception - While Navigating ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiviewcontroller

After lot of RnD and trial n error now I had to ask this question here. I am new to iOS and Objective C so I am not sure about the reasons of errors. I am getting error

> libc++abi,dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

When I try to navigate from one view controller to second view controller i.e. When I click button navigate it crashes n come up with this error

Now this is happening If I add some elements on the new view controller if I make new viewcontroller and keep it as it is no issues it works properly but then when it comes to add something on it.. it starts crashing

Here's the code on what I am doing is From one view controller to second I want to navigate and they are independent viewcontroller  I am not using navigation controller, just trying to achieve it with code..

```
    -(IBAction) tapForNavigation:(id) sender {

     DAViewController *daCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DAViewController"];
[self presentViewController:daCon animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

There is some problem with this only because everything else runs fine only when it comes to navigation its facing problem.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that the piece of code that you posted works fine if you do not modify the view controller after instantiating it from the storyboard? If so could you please post the code where you are populating your new view controller with data?

Comment: @Mischa : Data means adding Views on the view controller and I am adding it using storyboard.

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier=@"DAViewController" <==change the '=' to ':'

Comment: @Horst : that's typo edited in the question

Comment: I doubt that there are some IBoutlet connected wrongly.

Comment: Just to be sure: Are there any connections set up in the view controller you are trying to instantiate i.e. are when you select the view controller in your storyboard are there any outlets or actions set?

Comment: And: If you create another new view controller in your storyboard with class `UIViewController`, add some UI components and instantiate it instead of your `DAViewController` - does the same error occur?

Comment: @Mischa : I tried embed in Navigation Controller with the new viewcontroller now its working and not crashing ..Strange results i am not sure why ?

Comment: Have you checked the outlet / action connections?

Comment: @Mischa I did that no where it was showing that yellow triangles..

Comment: Hm. I can tell you there's nothing wrong with the code fragment you posted. I just tested it myself in a new project, added several UI elements to the second view controller and it works great. The problem must be somewhere else then. You will have to post more code and maybe a screenshot of your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to present your new viewController

```
-(IBAction) tapForNavigation:(id) sender {

    DAViewController *daCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DAViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:daCon animated:YES];

}
```